# Find a Specific row based on value of a column in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, row

I have a matrix with following structure

```
X    Y    ID
1    2    10
15   20    2
```

I want to find the index of row based on ID column. please advice me.

Comment: You mean `row = find(M(:,3) == 10)` ? Check [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) see if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html):

```
ind = find(M(:,3) == id)
```

You could add `'first'` or `'last'` like `find(M(:,3) > id, 'first')`.